# workflow rule using regex for workflow action on a richtext field

Tags: formula

I have the need to inspect a richtext field to find out if it has a value or not (think "Are their special instructions?"), however when people modify the field they often just "empty" it with spaces and or carriage returns which gives me a " `<br> <br>` " like value.

I have a simple rule of `regex(RichField__c, "[\\s<br>]*")` that is on creation and every edit, and an action that sets `RichField__c=null` if that regex evaluates. (Note that regex evaluates with an implied ^begin and end$, so the regex need not be `^[\\s<br>]+$` or similar)

I have tried many many regex expressions and I cannot evaluate "if the field contains only: space, tab, newline, character b, character r, less than or greater than characters". I have tried some desperate `regex(SUBSTITUTE(RichField__c),"<br>",""),"[\s]+")` like hacks as well. I can make the field work if it pure spaces, but new lines (or `<br>`) don't work.

There is something odd with RichText evaluation it seems, I can do this just fine with large text fields.

Note: Yes, I am editing with a new value and saving after every formula change.

Comment: I wonder if you can get more insight by debugging in Anonymous Apex. Can you find a failing record, query its Rich Text field, and see if you can get a pattern match in Apex? Then you can log the values that seem like they should match and don't.